# How do I pass a function with arguments in another function?

Tags: python, decorator

I was learning decorators and wonder why my code isn't working.

So basically I have a simple function for calculating the nth Fibonacci number. The decorator function is to calculate the time it takes for the Fibonacci function to run.

```
def timetocomplete(f):
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        f(*args)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"{f.__name__} took {end - start} seconds to complete")
    
    return wrap_func


@timetocomplete
def fib(a):
    if (a <= 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return (fib (a-2) + fib (a-1))
    
print(fib(5))
```

Commenting out the decorator, the fib function works fine but the using the decorator throws an error saying

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Your wrapper doesn't return the result of calling the function (or use the keyword arguments at all, but that's not causing your current problem).

Comment: Wouldnt the `timeit` be a better option here? The reason depends on whether you want to find out the overall time for the function to complete or each of the function call (because of recursion).

Comment: Yes the recursion is causing the problem here. I shouldn't have used the decorator like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of f in the wrap_func. This is because here:

`return (fib (a-2) + fib (a-1))`

If your function has been wrapped but the wrapper doesn't return anything, it will attempt to add Nonetype to Nonetype.

```
def timetocomplete(f):
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        res = f(*args)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"{f.__name__} took {end - start} seconds to complete")
        return res # <-- Here
return wrap_func


@timetocomplete
def fib(a):
    if (a <= 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return (fib (a-2) + fib (a-1))

print(fib(5))
```

This will work, but it will show you the timetocomplete for each iteration of `fib` If you're looking to wrap the entire fib sequence in the timetocomplete function, something like this would probably work just fine

```
def timetocomplete(f):
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        res = f(*args)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"{f.__name__} took {end - start} seconds to complete")
        return res

    return wrap_func

def fib(a):
    if (a <= 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return (fib (a-2) + fib (a-1))

@timetocomplete
def calculate_fib(a):
    return fib(a)

print(calculate_fib(5))
```

Comment: The previous error doesn't appear anymore. I get what I was doing wrong. But the timetocomplete function doesn't work the way I want it to.


It prints
>fib took 0.0 seconds to complete
>8

Comment: Understood. Check the edit

Comment: It's also useful to note that this entire program can be sped up using `functools cache` decorators (see: [functools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html)) - this will cache the value of each function call (ie: once `fib(2)` is called, it will not execute `fib(2)` again, but rather just look up the cached value)

Comment: This works and I understand the logic perfectly. Thanks.